# This Eclipse error icon in the package explorer is not showing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

The error icon in the package explorer is not showing (on top of the file icon), even though it shows on the right bar when the file is opened.

*.project* has *org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder* in its build command.

What else could be wrong?

Comment: Try to restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me (maybe some combination of the build command you can try):

```xml
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
```